# Linux routing table entry disappears

Tags: linux, routing

I run Fedora 20 (3.13.10-200.fc20.i686) inside VirtualBox on a Windows 7 SP1 host. The Ethernet adapter on the guest is configured as a Bridged Adapter in VBox, and gets an IP via DHCP. Here's the routing table on the guest:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         router          255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 p2p1
default         router          0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 p2p1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
```

Every so often (every day, perhaps), the 1st entry in the routing table disappears; as a result, I can make outbound connections to the intranet, but not to the Internet.

How do I find out who's modifying the routing table? Are there logs I could look at?

[P.S. I [asked this on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/725359/linux-routing-table-entry-disappears), but got no response, so trying here.]

Comment: What is `router` does it do NAT ? I can't think any reason you can't access Internet.

Comment: Yes, router does NAT. I don't know Linux routing well enough to give a more educated answer, but when the 1st entry disappears, I can't ping any IP on the Internet; when I add it back (manually), I can reach the Internet. I'm trying to find out who's messing with the routing table.

Comment: What is IP of `router`?

Comment: The IP is 192.168.1.1

Comment: Please use `ip route` to check the IPv4 routing table instead of `route`. The record looks simply wrong, why should you have a record like that at all?

Comment: Here's what ip route shows when the route exists:  0.0.0.0 via 192.168.1.1 dev p2p1  metric 1024\n  default via 192.168.1.1 dev p2p1  proto static  metric 1024\n  192.168.1.0/24 dev p2p1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.254

And when the route's gone, here's the output from `ip route`: 192.168.1.0/24 dev p2p1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.254